# Pandas inplace on self. variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'li'], [2, 'la'], [3, 'lu']], columns=(['index', 'col']))


class Test:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.data.set_index('index', inplace = True)


test1 = Test(df)
test2 = Test(df)

print(test1.data)
print(test2.data)
```

This throws an error: KeyError: "None of ['index'] are in the columns"

I realized that using the `set_index()` with `inplace = True` in the `__init__` method does not manipulate the `self.data` variable that belongs to the object instance. It actually sets `data` as a class variable shared by all instances.

When I avoid using `inplace` I don't get the error since now the `self.data` variable of the object instance is set.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'li'], [2, 'la'], [3, 'lu']], columns=(['index', 'col']))


class Test:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.data = self.data.set_index('index', inplace=False)


test1 = Test(df)
test2 = Test(df)

print(test1.data)
print(test2.data)
```

output:

```
       col
index    
1      li
2      la
3      lu
       col
index    
1      li
2      la
3      lu
```

What is the reason for this behaviour? It seems a bit counterintuitive to me that a class variable is set while using a function on a variable prefaced with `.self`

Is there a reason or advantage to use the `inplace = True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is related to pandas but more to the fact that Python is a pass-by-object-reference language ([see explanations here](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)).

Consider the following example that has a similar behavior as in your example:

```py
class Test2:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.data.append(2)

A=[0,1]
test1 = Test2(A)
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Modifications to the underlying object `A` is persisted (because it is a list and lists are mutables just like pandas dataframes).

In your example, when using `self.data.set_index('index', inplace = True)` a new dataframe will NOT be created so similarly to the above example the underlying object `df` is persisted.

Consider the following addition to you code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'li'], [2, 'la'], [3, 'lu']], columns=(['index', 'col']))

class Test:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.data.set_index('index', inplace = True)


print(df.columns)
test1 = Test(df)
print(df.columns)
```

Outputs:

```py
Index(['index', 'col'], dtype='object')
Index(['col'], dtype='object')
```

`df` was changed.

Finally the following would have worked:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'li'], [2, 'la'], [3, 'lu']], columns=(['index', 'col']))

class Test:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.data.set_index('index', inplace = True)

test1 = Test(pd.DataFrame([[1, 'li'], [2, 'la'], [3, 'lu']], columns=(['index', 'col'])))
test2 = Test(pd.DataFrame([[1, 'li'], [2, 'la'], [3, 'lu']], columns=(['index', 'col'])))

print(test1.data)
print(test2.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't create the object of the Test class for the second time. Once you have set the index for test1 object there is no more 'index' column in the dataframe for test2. Just modify the same code as :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'li'], [2, 'la'], [3, 'lu']], columns=(['index', 'col']))


class Test:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        print(self.data)
        self.data.set_index('index', inplace = True)


test1 = Test(df)
print(test1.data)
```